# MapBox style hides points at low zoom levels

Tags: zooming, mapbox, tippecanoe

I have a geojson file of thousands of points (each point is a Feature in a big FeatureCollection) and I create a tileset with tippecanoe:

```
tippecanoe -o /home/ubuntu/positions.mbtiles -Z 0 -z 14 /home/ubuntu/positions.json.gz --force
```

Whatever tippecanoe options I've tried, the result is always the following:

- features (points) show correctly even at zooms < 15 in the tileset page, or in the "select data" tab of the style layer
- most features disappear as the zoom levels drops (only 1 or 2 points are visible out of thousands at zoom below 13-14) in the "style" view

[image]

I'm displaying the features in the style as "circles" so no icon-allow-overlap should in theory be necessary.

How to proceed so that most points would still be visible at low zoom levels?

Comment: This does look strange. I don't see any obvious mistake (apart from `-z 14`, but since you said you tried lots of options, you probably tried with a higher maxzoom). Can you post a full-setup example with the sources and the generated map (or reproduce the issue with a public or anonymized dataset)?